# how to send xml with an image on objective C

Tags: objective-c, xml, web-services, datahandler

How do I attach an image to an XML file in Objective-C to POST to a WebService?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<SaveRequest>
    <PictureDataFile></PictureDataFile>
    <PictureDataName>sample</PictureDataName>
</SaveRequest>
```

How do I append the image data into 'PictureDataFile'?

And in my objective-C I have,

```
NSString *post = [self loadFileName:@"SaveRequest" ofType:@"xml"];
//loads the xml into a string
NSMutableData *postData = [[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding    allowLossyConversion:YES] mutableCopy];
[postData appendData:paramBuilder.imageData];
//paraBuilder.imageData contains a UIImage in NSData
```

I can see the server receive the request, but no image data is received. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This kinda depends on what the webservice is expecting.

Comment: It is expecting MIME type, application/octet-stream

Comment: It's expecting that one node's content to have the MIME type application/octet-stream? That seems strange.

Comment: Does it? the xml request when received from the web looks like : <PictureDataFile>223lierwee222s5....etc</PictureDataFile>

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, in case anyone runs into the same issue:
convert the nsdata to base64 by using

```
[NSData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:]
```

therefore attach the base64 data to the node like this :

```
[postData appendData:[imageData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength]];
```